# make data grid visible on click

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have this data grid  where I am placing all my buttons

```
<Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,90,0,4" Width="186">
   <Button x:Name="B1" Content="B1" Height="18" Margin="73,0,59,16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="B1"/>
   <Button x:Name="B2" Content="B2" Height="18" Margin="0,0,-2,16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="B2_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="57"/>
 </Grid>
```

I have the grid collapased on start. But when a button {testGrid} is clicked, I want the grid to ne visible.
Here is my code

```
   namespace project.Test
    {
        public partial class MainPage : UserControl
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
```

**EDUTED**

```
        private void testGrid_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             FrameworkElement ButtonGrid = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindName("ButtonGrid") as FrameworkElement;

    if ( ButtonGrid.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
        ButtonGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    else
        ButtonGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: ButtonGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; ???

Comment: that highlights it red under it

Comment: it says the name doesnt exist in current context

Comment: where do you put your ButtonGrid? you need to show more code

Comment: Please look at the edited question. Now I have the ButtonGrid but it still gives me error at ButtonGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; It gives me null reference exception.

Comment: You need to show your full xaml code, esp. where you put your Grid

Comment: ok but that is like 4000 lines

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4812/discussion-between-autolycus-and-xin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you move your `Grid` outside of your `DataTemplate` it will work. :)

However if you really need to put it in a `DataTemplate`, as long as your `Button` is at the same level as the `Grid`, you should still be able to find it.

Say your xaml code looks like this,

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="controlstoryboardactionrefissue.MainPage" Width="640" Height="480">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Height="128" Background="#FFE7C0C0" Width="333">
                <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="31,29,0,0" Click="myButton_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="175,198,0,0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then the code behind,

```
    private void myButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myButton = (Button)sender;

        var grid = myButton.Parent as Grid;

        if (grid != null)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps. :)